# How to change property of a certain area on a widget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Say I have an opaque window for the user to click and drag on, creating a selection rectangle. Is it possible to make just that rectangular area transparent, leaving the rest of the window opaque? Kind of like this image. The black being the opaque part and the white being the transparent part. All part of the same widget.
Edit: Transparent as in being able to see behind the window.

[image]

Comment: With "transparent" do you mean that you can see *behind* the *whole* window, or that you have other widgets behind that and you want to be able to see them?

Comment: I meant behind the whole window, sorry I'll clear that up in the post as well.

Comment: is that going to be just transparent (so it will be able to capture mouse events), or should it allow to "click through"?

Comment: I just want to get the coordinates of the transparent area, the user won't be doing anything inside it.